# What episode is this from on Batman?

Tags: tv, batman, episode-identification

Anyone know what episode on the 1960s Batman TV show this is from?

[image]

Comment: Questions about the One True Batman are always welcome.

Comment: @Spencer - This was far and away the best on-screen adaptation, although [Batman and Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_and_Robin_(serial)) was also excellent

Answer (score 6):

[The Unkindest Tut of All](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519555/) - (Batman 1966; Season 3 Episode 6).

These are Tut's henchmen in disguise. You'll be pleased to learn that Batman and Robin managed to defeat them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Valorum did not recall.

Comment: It's a good episode. Batman's identity is revealed and there's some excellent ham acting by Tut

Comment: Tut even bugged the Batmobile and traced it back to the Batcave on his Tutscope.